# dplyr override all but the first occurrences of a value within a group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a grouped data_frame with a "tag" column taking on values "0" and "1". In each group, I need to find the first occurrence of "1" and change all the remaining occurrences to "0". Is there a way to achieve it in dplyr?

For example, let's take "iris" data and let's add the extra "tag" column:

```
data(iris)
set.seed(1)
iris$tag <- sample( c(0, 1), 150, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.8, 0.2))
giris <- iris %>% group_by(Species)
```

In "giris", in the "setosa" group I need to keep only the first occurrence of "1" (i.e. in 4th row) and set the remaining ones to "0". This seems a bit like applying a mask or something...

Is there a way to do it? I have been experimenting with "which" and "duplicated" but I did not succeed. I have been thinking about filtering the "1"s only, keeping them, then joining with the remaining set, but this seems awkward, especially for a 12GB data set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dplyr option:

```
mutate(giris, newcol = as.integer(tag & cumsum(tag) == 1))
```

Or

```
mutate(giris, newcol = as.integer(tag & !duplicated(tag)))
```

Or using data.table, same approach, but modify by reference:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(giris)
giris[, newcol := as.integer(tag & cumsum(tag) == 1), by = Species]
```

Comment: A very nice and clever use of cumsum :-). Just out of curiosity: any idea on how to generalize it if I had "a"s and "b"s instead of "0"s and "1"s? Or if there were three levels? Again, this is just curiosity

Comment: @rpl, for "a"s and "b"s it would be `as.integer(tag == "a" & cumsum(tag == "a") == 1)`. The difference is that 0/1 are interpreted as TRUE/FALSE and can simply be summed or used in logical comparisons while for "a" and "b" we have to write the check explicitly.

Comment: Ah, indeed. This is really ingenious in its simplicity. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @rpl, I added an approach with duplicated. You can easily use that for other cases too if you modify it to: `mutate(giris, newcol = as.integer(tag == "a" & !duplicated(tag)))` for example

Answer (score 2):

We can try

```
res <- giris %>%
         group_by(Species) %>% 
         mutate(tag1 = ifelse(cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(tag)<0))!=1, 0, tag))

table(res[c("Species", "tag1")])
#            tag1
#Species      0  1
# setosa     49  1
# versicolor 49  1
# virginica  49  1
```